# Spring project cannot find dotenv file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dotenv

I set up a db connection w encryption, I have a dotenv file to store the data on it locally, but when I run it I get this error:

java: package io.github.cdimascio.dotenv does not exist

the .env file is in the root directory of the project and it definitely has the correct information in it.

This is my main application class:

```
package com.coursework.chatter;

import com.coursework.chatter.config.DatabaseConnectionTest;
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Objects;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ChatterApplication {

    static {
        // Load .env variables
        Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
        System.out.println("DB_URL: " + dotenv.get("DB_URL"));  // Debug log
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", Objects.requireNonNull(dotenv.get("DB_URL")));
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", Objects.requireNonNull(dotenv.get("DB_USERNAME")));
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", Objects.requireNonNull(dotenv.get("DB_PASSWORD")));
        System.setProperty("DB_DRIVER", Objects.requireNonNull(dotenv.get("DB_DRIVER")));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ChatterApplication.class, args);
        DatabaseConnectionTest dbTest = context.getBean(DatabaseConnectionTest.class);
        try {
            dbTest.testConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.coursework</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Chatter</name>
    <description>Chatter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

These are my dependencies,

it works on someone else branch but not on mine for some reason?